# SQL Server : account needs access to data in another database

Tags: sql-server

**Scenario**: a desktop application connects to a SQL Server database using a restricted account. However application now requires them to have access to data in a table in another database (on same server)

How do I grant that account in database 1 to have select access to the table in database 2?

Comment: Add a user, linked to the same login, on the other database and grant that user permission to `SELECT` from the table.

Comment: better still set up a certificate based user....

Comment: Thanks Larnu; adding a second user to the same login was the step I was unsure of. This has helped resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

`grant select on [schema].[table] to [user]` on the object in the other database